# Is the JWT token stored in the same table as the DRF token?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm hoping that someone could please clear up a confusion I have with JWT and regular token authentication in `django_rest_auth` and `django_rest_framework`.

I'm using django_rest_auth with JWT `(REST_USE_JWT = True)`. I am using the `rest_auth.registration` views and the `rest_auth` views and have set my default authentication class to `'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'`.

I have included the urls from rest_auth and set up the following url`url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)`, from `rest_framework_jwt` docs.

When I register a new user, I expect the following code from the rest_auth RegisterView to be run:

```
if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
    self.token = jwt_encode(self.user)
```

But in the Django Admin, I see that there is the Auth Token table, 'Tokens', with a token that looks like a normal token if I had used Django's built in Token Authentication. Indeed, when I go to /rest-auth/login endpoint, it returns this same token, e.g. `{"key":"6b705cbab083833c38414d4c6e4970c0abbb0c9f"}`. However, when I go to the api-token-auth/ endpoint for this user, I get the JWT token: `{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJvYmVydEByb2JlcnRjaHUuY28udWsiLCJleHAiOjE0NjY2ODI5MjcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoicm9iZXJ0QHJvYmVydGNodS5jby51ayJ9.IvJIQBY95TrQp3V483GVdpV0fQKedMk9hWEFytMRidU"}`

Are these keys and token interchangeable? Could I use both tokena for the same user? Surely, I should only have one token option to access protected endpoints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://jwt.io) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). The JWT is not supposed to be stored anywhere which is one of the benefits over the drf tokens - you don't hit the db on every request. Also if you want to only use the JWT for authentication you should get rid of the endpoint for token authentication (the one that comes with drf).

Comment: Thanks, I guess my follow-up question is why then is the token created in `django_rest_auth` when I have set the JWT flag to True? Or is my setup not correct?

Comment: As far as I remember you have to remove `rest_framework.authtoken` from your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` and also if you've used the `ObtainAuthToken` view from the drf before switching to JWT it just calls Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user) and the token will stay in the db...

Comment: Also look here: http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/ for example settings - you can setup multiple authentication classes. If you want only JWT auth, leave only that in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me realise that the latest `django_rest_auth` library I have installed via pip, 0.7.0 at time of writing, has not implemented JWT yet, but I was looking at the latest source on github assuming it was, hence the login endpoint was still setting the DRF token, regardless of the status of the JWT settings flag.